# Not able to create color swatches Magento ver. 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

Preconditions

```
Magento ver. 2.2.4
Developer mode/Production Mode
```

Steps to reproduce

```
Add your own colors
```

Expected result

```
You should be able to add as many colors as you want.
```

Actual result

```
After 39 color swatches, new colors are not saved even though you still get the "You saved the product attribute." success message.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could increase `max_input_vars` from your php.ini.
The problem was the limitation of `max_input_vars` which limits the number of parameters while sending to server on your post request each time you click on `Save` swatch attribute.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem i set it up to 5000 and its working.